# upgrading Xcode 4.0.1 to 4.1 giving compilation error for iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction, xcode4, llvm

I have new changed the Snow leopard with Lion OS x and Xcode 4.0.1 with 4.1. The iPhone code was working fine on Xcode 4.0.1. Now in Xcode 4.1 it giving errors mostly related to LLVM GCC 4.2. I have tried with changing the compiler's different options available. Can body know the issue and help me out of this.

Comment: Can you show what the exact errors are?

Comment: I am getting about 245 Errors. And most of the errors are "Expected declaration specifiers before '-' token".

Comment: Can you perhaps show a screenshot of some of these errors in the code? It would be nice to fix them instead of messing with SDKs. But I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the compiler version on the target and double click it then you have to change it from there.Try it,i may solve your problem.
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/3/21/compiler-options-in-xcode-gcc-or-llvm.html
check this url

Comment: Thanks for response, Presently I have change Compiler for c/c++/Objective C to LLVM GCC 4.2. Is that correct.

Comment: I have tried with all the options available for Compiler in Build and Target, but there is no fruitful result.

Answer (score 0):

I know that when I upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.1, the update via App Store removed iOS SDK 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2, leaving only 4.3.

This gave me compile errors because my base SDK was 4.0, it required the 4.0 SDK files to compile, I was lucky enough to have everything backed up and I copied my SDKs back over to Lion into

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

This was the only issue I had with the upgrade, hope this helps.

Comment: You mean It is not possible to run Xcode 4.0.1 build to Xcode 4.1 with IOS 4.3.

Comment: No, what I meant was that when I upgraded to Xcode 4.1, the install process removed iOS SDKs 4.0 to 4.2, you should be able to download these somewhere and they work fine by just placing them back where they should be.