# Xcode 4.3: How to install earlier SDKs?

Tags: ios, xcode

This might be a duplicate of [Is there a way to install older iOS SDKs in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320235/is-there-a-way-to-install-older-ios-sdks-in-xcode)?. I'm not interested in backwards compatibility, I'm just trying to use Apple samples.

The Apple [Quartz Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) is not working under Xcode 4.3.1 (4E1019) using iOS 5.1 SDK. iOS 5.1 is the only Base SDK available. The deployment target is 3.2, and I've tried compiling with both LLVM-GCC and LLVM-3.1.

From Preferences -> Downloads, I believe I have all Components and Documentation installed that Xcode offers. Unfortunately, I don't see any mobile libraries other than iOS 5.1.

How does one install earlier iOS SDKs so I can continue using Apple Demos? Or is this more Apple alpha/beta junk that never should have been released for general consumption?

Jeff

Answer (score 5):

It's much easier to just fix that sample code. Here's what I did:

1. Download the code and open QuartzDemo.xcodeproj
2. View > Navigators > Show Issue Navigator.
3. Click "Validate Project Settings" in the first issue. Then "Perform Changes", and "Disable" snapshots.
4. In AppDelegate.m, comment out this line:

> @property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIWindow *window;
>
> Build and Run.